# getting inconsistent results with SQL query and need assistance determining why

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wrote a simple SQL query to count the number of records in a table in a database. I've run it in MySQL successfully and it returns a count of 4711 each time without fail which is correct. When I converted this over to C# and try to run this in my program to return the count so I can reference it and display to my users it returns 0 100% of the time. Need some assistance figuring out what I'm doing wrong. I verified correct username and password and that I can already successfully access the database from visual studio without error and see the table I'm trying to do this count on.

C# code:

```
public string SQLDataTotalCalls()
        {
            SqlConnection connection = null;
            try
            {
                var dataSet = new DataSet();

                connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=databaseservername;Initial Catalog=nameOfDatabase;User Id=myusername;Password=mypassword";
                connection.Open();

                var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(SOURCEID) AS 'MYCOUNT' "
                                             + "FROM [databasename].[databasename].[CmsCallHistory] "
                                             +"WHERE disposition = 2 and DISPSPLIT in ('183','186','187','174') AND SEGSTOP BETWEEN '2017-03-22 05:00:00.000' and '2017-03-23 05:00:00.000'",
                    connection)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.Text
                };

                var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter {SelectCommand = command};

                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

                return dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MYCOUNT"].ToString();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message, e);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }

        }
```

Original SQL working query in case it is needed:

```
SELECT COUNT(SOURCEID) AS 'MYCOUNT'
FROM [databasename].[databasename].[CmsCallHistory]
WHERE disposition = 2 and DISPSPLIT in ('183','186','187','174') AND SEGSTOP BETWEEN '2017-03-22 05:00:00.000' and '2017-03-23 05:00:00.000'
```

I get 0 errors when this runs in visual studio so I'm hoping its just some type of syntax error in the authentication string but at this point I have no clue.

Comment: have you tried to removed the \n on the var command and replaced by space?

Comment: Change your `CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure` to `CommandType = CommandType.Text`

Comment: since it is not a storedproc, @TriV is right. you have to change the storedproc to text

Comment: I just changed it to text. see question to also reflect change. when i run it, it still returns 0 as the count.

Comment: replace the \n with space not just deleting it because it will be something like "SELECT COUNT(SOURCEID) AS **'MYCOUNT'FROM** [databasename].[databasename].[CmsCallHistory]..." when run

Comment: You can't use 'SqlCommand', 'SqlConnection', etc.,  with a MySQL provider. Those are specifically used with Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: @crowcoder this is microsoft SQL server. sorry for my miscommunication. i'm not an SQL person at all.

Comment: I figured you either had identical MSSQL and MySql servers (since you got no exception) or you mis-tagged the question. You should edit your question and tag to prevent further confusion.

Comment: I suggest you use Sql Profiler to do a trace while you run this code. There is no visible reason why this is not working. Either the code you have shown is not representative of the actual code running, or there is something else that we have no insight into. A trace might tell you immediately what the problem is.

Comment: ok i will try that. i also re-tagged the post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I could give you all correct answers as your data as a whole helped me out with probably I probably would have encountered in the future. But turns out the Database I was trying to access was returning a string of 0 because it actually was 0. The table was on a rolling 30 day retention policy and just so happens that time hit right after I queried the data from sql management studio and before I typed out the method that ran the Query in visual studio.

Again thank you all for the help and the question contains the most accurate and up to date working code.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't

```
Rows[0]["Item"]
```

Be

```
Rows[0]["MYCOUNT"]
```

Comment: my bad. fixed that. for consistence you are correct but i don't believe it matters. when I run it with MYCOUNT i still get 0. and if I'm wrong and it does matter then that's not the source of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(SOURCEID) AS 'MYCOUNT'\n"
              + "FROM [databasename].[databasename].[CmsCallHistory]\n"
              +"WHERE disposition = 2 and 
                DISPSPLIT in ('183','186','187','174') AND SEGSTOP BETWEEN '2017-03-22 05:00:00.000' and '2017-03-23 05:00:00.000'",
                connection)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };
```

this should be like this since \n is not readable in SQL queries as i tried it and actually it is concatinated with your statement

```
var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(SOURCEID) AS 'MYCOUNT' " //see spacing here
              + "FROM [databasename].[databasename].[CmsCallHistory] "//see spacing here
              +"WHERE disposition = 2 and 
                DISPSPLIT in ('183','186','187','174') AND SEGSTOP BETWEEN '2017-03-22 05:00:00.000' and '2017-03-23 05:00:00.000'",
                connection)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.Text
            };
```

Comment: I removed the /n and it still only returns 0. corrected question to show removal of /n.

Comment: the second comment can make it too

Comment: see the spacing after **'MYCOUNT'** and **[databasename].[databasename].[CmsCallHistory]** to provide a proper statement

Comment: tried that. count still returns 0. If any of these little things were the issue wouldn't i be getting some type of error thrown?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure` to `CommandType = CommandType.Text`

Comment: also added comment from this on the question. i made the change and the count still returns 0